# Camera options definitions not recognized in ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using the Cordova camera plugin into a Ionic app,

if I define the options parameters using the definitions as for example:

```
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
```

the ionic -serve -l doesn't work, it displays 2 empty devices (iOS, Android) in the browser,

if I use the corresponding numbers instead of symbols (0 for destinationType, 1 for sourceType) it works (and even the ionicview app works fine with the camera).

What can be the problem?

Comment: you can't test it in browser only in device

Comment: Try in devices it will not work in browser

Comment: so do you mean that in general, I should avoid the browser as testing environment?

Comment: The solution, as indicated by a classmate of the Multiplatform Mobile App Development with Web Technologies course on Coursera, is to put under condition the section where the definitions are referred:                                    if (typeof Camera !== "undefined") {
  // Provided code here :
  var cameraOptions = { ... };
  $scope.takePicture = function() { ... }
} else {
  // Alternate version if the camera is unavailable
  $scope.takePicture = function() {
    console.log("Camera unavailable");
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

The solution, as indicated by a classmate of the Multiplatform Mobile App Development with Web Technologies course on Coursera, is to put under condition the section where the definitions are referred as follows:

```
if (typeof Camera !== "undefined") {
  // Provided code here :
  var cameraOptions = { ...Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL };
  $scope.takePicture = function() { ... }
} else {
  // Alternate version if the camera is unavailable
  $scope.takePicture = function() {
    console.log("Camera unavailable");
  }
}
```